# Spritekit - Cut the rope, Magic Hat effect. Calculating speed of sprite and firing out of the object at same speed and in direction of the object

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have two portals. When the ball hits the first portal, I want the ball to reappear at the second portal.

1. The ball must reappear at the same speed as when it goes through it
2. The ball must fire out in the same direction as the portal. (If portal is at 45 degrees, the ball must fire out at that angle

At the moment, I am using an SKAction just to move the ball to the next portal.

```
-(void)collisionBallPortal1ToPortal2{

SKAction *moveToNextPortal = [SKAction runBlock:^{
ballNode.position = portal2.position;

}];

SKAction *ballNodePortalMove = [SKAction sequence:@[moveToNextPortal]];
[ballNode runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:ballNodePortalMove count:1]];
}
```

Clearly this code does not do it. The speed is maintained however when it arrives at the second portal. It just needs to fire out in the same direction.

1. I think I need to first calculate the speed of the ball
2. Work out the angle of the portal
3. Use the calculated speed to apply an impulse in the direction of the second portal.

Can anyone help? I need the whole code. I dont know how to calculate the PORTALDIRECTION and use the BALLLAUNCHIMPULSE.

```
 ballNode.physicsBody.velocity = self.physicsBody.velocity;
 [ballNode.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(ballLaunchImpulse*cosf(portalDirection),ballLaunchImpulse*sinf(portalDirection))];
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at the `velocity` property of the `physicsBody`.  This will give you `dx` and `dy`, which if everything is at right angles, should be very easy to just flip the signs on depending on the direction.

Comment: You say easy, still struggling. Are you able to help by giving me some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I think what you are trying to do is similar to [Valve's Portal](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/), and that's how I designed this.  I do not have complete familiarity with the game mechanic you are mimicking, but I hope it's close.

```
-(void)ballFromPortal1:(SKNode*)portal1 toPortal2:(SKNode*)portal2 { 
    // If a portal is against a wall, I assume that its zRotation is facing away from wall as such: 
    // | 
    // <- (| 
    // | 
    // All units in radians 

    // Determine which side of the hemisphere each portal is on 
    BOOL portal1Left = true; 
    BOOL portal2Left = true; 
    if ((portal1.zRotation >= 0.0) && (portal1.zRotation <= M_PI+0.0001)) { 
        portal1Left = false; 
    } 
    if ((portal2.zRotation >= 0.0) && (portal2.zRotation <= M_PI+0.0001)) { 
        portal2Left = false; 
    } 

    // Calculate the magnitude of the velocity of the ball 
    float oldBallVelocity = sqrtf((self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx * self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx) + (self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy * self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy)); 

    // Calculate the new direction depending on which side of the hemisphere the portals are on 
    float newBallDirection = 0.0; 
    if (portal1Left == portal2Left) { 
        // Calculate the ball direction pre-portal 
        float oldBallDirection = atan2f(self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy, self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx); 
        // Calculate ball direction relative to portal 1 
        float rotationRelativeToPortal1 = oldBallDirection - portal1.zRotation; 
        // If the portals are on the same side 
        newBallDirection = portal2.zRotation - rotationRelativeToPortal1; 

        // Set the position and velocity of the ball to the new location 
        self.ballNode.position = portal2.position; 
        self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(oldBallVelocity * cosf(newBallDirection), oldBallVelocity * sinf(newBallDirection)); 
    } else { 
        // Calculate the ball direction pre-portal 
        float oldBallDirection = atan2f(self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy, self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx) - M_PI_2; 
        // Calculate ball direction relative to portal 1 
        float rotationRelativeToPortal1 = oldBallDirection - portal1.zRotation; 
        // If the portals are on different sides 
        newBallDirection = portal2.zRotation - rotationRelativeToPortal1; 

        // Set the position and velocity of the ball to the new location 
        self.ballNode.position = portal2.position; 
        self.ballNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(oldBallVelocity * sinf(newBallDirection), oldBallVelocity * cosf(newBallDirection)); 
    }
}
```

I put a lot of comments in the code, which should help you understand it.  I allow you to have two portals that are passed into it, and it should move the ball to portal 2.  I would recommend a simple check in the `didSimulatePhysics` method, testing if the ball is touching portal 1 or 2, and then call the method I provided.

This was fun to write, and I hope it helps!

Edit: Updated with the latest code from the chat.

Comment: This is great!!! For some reason, the move to Portal 2 did not work at first. I then put in a SKAction and it did the trick.

Comment: The only area which I believe that I should of expanded on, is the portal locations. The portal can be anywhere on the screen at any angle. For example Portal 1 could be at the bottom of the screen, with portal 2 on the left hand side facing inwards. Anyway you can expand the code so, it works from all locations and angles?

Comment: fyi, similar to cut the rope, Magic hat portals :)

Comment: @user3482617 What happens when you put the portal on the bottom?  I think I made the code handle it.  I wasn't familiar with Cut the Rope all that much, so I kinda guessed. :)  It's weird that you need an `SKAction` to move it.

Comment: Portal 2 at top, Portal 1 at bottom, ball goes into portal 1, comes out of 2 but fires to the left. Should follow the same direction

Comment: Seems like portals being in different locations causes the ball impulse to react differently. Just did a test, portals facing the direction in different areas of the screen caused impulses in different directions

Comment: if (portal1Left == portal2Left) {
    // If the portals are on the same side
    newBallDirection = portal2.zRotation - rotationRelativeToPortal1 - M_PI;
}
Try this instead for the hemisphere correction.  Just replace the first bit of the `if` statement.

Comment: A little better, but now fires off to the bottom right, instead of straight down in line with the direction of the portal :(

Comment: @user3482617  Yeah, my bad, stick with what I said, and try removing the ` - M_PI` portion entirely.

Comment: Okay so, after correcting with M_PI_2, goes to the middle and drops straight. But now loses speed. Starts from 0 velocity.

Comment: And as a result, another problem, Portal 1 facing inward on left hand side, Portal 2 facing inward on right hand side. Ball goes into Portal 1 but comes out of Portal 2 rightwards and flys off screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97733/discussion-between-gliderman-and-user3482617).